# React Native - No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am facing an issue, Whenever I try to build using `react-native run-android`, the build fails with the following error.

> \?\E:\projects\deets-mobile-cp\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:88:
>   AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory'
>   in package 'android'
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>
>   > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

I have researched about the error but failed to resolve it. Whats going wrong I can't figure out. I am using gradle `v3.1.2`.

Does anybody have idea whats going wrong

React Native`v0.53.3`

**android/app.js**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile project(':instabug-reactnative')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3") {
        force=true
    }  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-braintree-xplat')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0') 
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1"
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0' //this decides your firebase SDK version
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0") {
      force = true;
   }
   compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0") {
      force = true;
   }
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
    compile(project(':react-native-google-signin')){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile(project(':react-native-geolocation-service')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile project(':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc')
}
```

`gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace`

> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process
>     resources, see aapt output above for details.
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:512)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)

Comment: I am getting this but because I upgraded `react-native-fcm` to version 16, which supports Android 8 and I am having a bad time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and looking at your dependancies we're both using react-native-braintree-xplat.

Braintree has recently updated the library to support Android 28, and the issue comes from there.

I'm not an android expert but you should force
com.braintreepayments.api to version 2.17.0

I do it in my project build.gradle with

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ......
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.17.0'
            }
        }
        ......
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working by forcing the api:braintree api to `2.17.0`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue, I found that one of my package was causing the issue(changing the build tool versions and using the resolution strategy didn't help me.). So what I did was I removed the packages one by one and tried to build the app. Fortunately this error was being triggered by one of the package i was using. So I had to replace it.

So I recommend you to do the same try removing the packages one by one and see if the issue is being caused by any package.

Try to remove the following packages first:

```
compile project(':rn-fetch-blob') 
compile project(':react-native-braintree-xplat')
compile(project(':react-native-google-signin')
```

Comment: I tried removing the packages and found that `braintree-xplat` was causing it. Thanks.